# Sending ajax request and receiving response (synchronised)

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest, response

I am sending ajax request and handle the response  in my js/html application. The device is **Windows Mobile CE**, there is no jquery support and the device browser (IE) does not support eventhandlers, so i can not use asynch calls. Anyway, my problem is, before sending the event, i want to display a *please wait message* and upon receiving response i want to hide it again.

```
function sendRequest() {
// make please wait visible
document.getElementById("pleasewait").style.display = "block";
console.log("pleasewait visible.");

var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
// synch call

XHR.send(sendData);

// suppose it takes 20-30 seconds
console.log("response received :" + XHR.responseText);

XHR.open('POST', 'url', false); 

// make please wait hidden
document.getElementById("pleasewait").style.display = "none";
}
```

But, when I run it, the pleasewait element is made visible when we receive response (not before sending) and becomes immediatelty hidden again even if the process takes for example 20-30 seconds. The console messages are displayed in the correct order, but the please wait element is not updated correctly. I tried some setTimeouts but no desired result. I can not add some jsfiddle because it is hard to implement ajax request handler on th remote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Browsers will *freeze* when doing **synchronous** ajax request hence the `synchronous` request prevents the display re-flow!

Only solution I will suggest is to use `setTimeout` with `0` duration!

```js
function sendRequest() {
  document.getElementById("pleasewait").style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(function() {
    var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
    XHR.send(sendData);
    console.log("response received :" + XHR.responseText);
    XHR.open('POST', 'url', false);
    document.getElementById("pleasewait").style.display = "none";
  }, 0);
}
```

**Note:** [Here](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8819) is a some relevant information!